# How to detect when cursor move then data will be update in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let say I have two text boxes named:

`Price`    = _______
`Discount` = _______

I also have a label named `Total`.

What I want is that when I key in some value in `Price` textbox and then I move the mouse and click on the next textbox which is `Discount`, the `Total` label will have the value from `Price` textbox.

Currently I've this:

when I click <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> on my keyboard it will update:

```
private void TxtPrice_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key == Key.Return) || (e.Key == Key.Tab))
    {
        try
        {
          //some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //some code
        }
    }
}
```

I want the data to be updated without the need to click <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I want those functions to be done at the code behind. Is it possible to do that? If yes, How would it be?

Comment: You should probably look into MVVM and binding rather than code-behind.  It will make things easier in the long run.

Comment: @KevinCook I do not think that MVVM is easier for a newbie *- ha that joke -* as writing it simple in code behind. With the code behind tactic all logic is in the same place and can be simple revisited.

Comment: @Hille I said easier "in the long run". There are benefits to writing business logic without being bound inside of event handlers for both testing and maintenance.  I guess if most of your programs are single page crud applications (since your comment suggests all the logic is in one spot) then you have never probably had to deal with complex projects and have limited your knowledge by not trying MVVM.

Comment: @KevinCook Yea most of my programs are single page ones because those are little programs with one functionality or some testing. But I do not use MVVM on large scale as it's not necessary and at work we are having our own conventions... **But lets get back on topic...** I said that for a beginner I would not recommend MVVM as it's to complex. He/She should first learn the basics of the language befor using some technics he most probably never heard befor??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each TextBox has a `LostFocus` event which is triggered on the loss of its focus from mouse or keyboard.

Then within your `TextBox_LostFocus()`-function you do something like

```
Total.Content = Price.Text;
```

to fill in the current price.

---

May implement some security functionality for checking if the amount in the price TextBox is a double or an int.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use the `TextChanged`-Event for this

```
private void TxtPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TotalLabel.Text = TxtPrice.Text;
}



private void TxtDiscount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Logic for discount 
    //And update TotalLabel
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `GotFocus`-Event on the Discount TextBox
Like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Discount" GotFocus="Discount_GotFocus"></TextBox>
```

and in the code behind:

```
private void Discount_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Why should we update the `total` label on focus? That means if you tab in the empty textbox and write an amount in it, then nothing will change after setting the focus on another object. If you then focus the textbox the second time, the `total` label will be updated with the old value.